# PC waking up: powercfg -devicequery wake_armed says HID keyboard (USB) wakes it even when that is UNPLUGGED. Apparent Cause: AMD SMBus Driverupdate

Tags: windows-11, power-management, amd-radeon, amd-ryzen

Why" and "how" can  something that is **unplugged** be causing a computer to wake up?   Has anyone else had this specific problem and found the cause?   Is it related to "Allow  this computer to turn off this device to save power" (and USB selective suspend it enabled) greyed out?

Desktop computer (running W/11 64 bit, Ryzen 3200G CPU; MS b450Pro mobo)  began waking up a couple minutes after being put to sleep, and with "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" listing the hid keyboard  as the cause - even when it was turned off and or  unplugged the moment the  Sleep command was initiated, and with **"Allow this device to wake up the computer" being deselected in  Device Manager.** Likewise for the USB mouse.

I tested this  many times by  quickly unplugging the  peripheral  or other times turning off the USB switch as soon as I hit my Sleep key. ( I have long used a script to enter sleep (C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,3,0) which is hotkeyed to Scroll Lock, which works fine).

Since the computer was sleeping well before a AMD chipset and AMD software update then I surmised that one of these was the problem. I had used  Auto-Detect and Install to install AMD chipset drivers but I   chosen not  to install the AMD Ryzen Power Plan since I did not want it  to mess with anything up, but just choose to install the upgrade AMD PSP driver  (a trusted execution environment subsystem) and the AMD SMBus Driver (a chipset on the motherboard primarily utilised for communication with the power source for ON/OFF instructions) and after uninstalling the updated  PSP  and SMBus drivers (both of which AMD now says do not have the latest driver) then the sleep-wake issue is gone, and sleep works  as before.

Still, how can a driver update  result in something that is unplugged  waking up  a computer even when "Allow this device to wake up the computer" is deselected?

Comment: You do whatever you like, but questions such as "is anyone else having this issue" have more their place in social forums, not in our Q&A site.

Comment: Well, it is a question, albeit with a seeming answer, but they "why" and "how" something that is unplugged be causing a computer to wake up is itself perplexing, and I will make that query clearer.